# What does the syntax of this line of code mean ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1"))?

Tags: c#, syntax

Why is `Label` in parentheses at the beginning. What is happening here?

```
((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1")).Text
```

Comment: Thats the cast operator. [`FindControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `Control` and `(Label)`  will cast this control to `Label`. That works because `Label` inherits from `Control`. It's necessary because  `Control` doesn't have a `Text` property but `Label` has.

Comment: Please read basics of `c#` language, or at least [Casting and Type Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) article.

Comment: It would be beneficial to you to read the documentation for `c#`. Asking fundamental questions about a programming language here on SO is not a good way to learn, or to make friends.

Comment: Dunno if you have vb.net background or not, but it is similar to vb.net `DirectCast()`

Answer (score 2):

What this code does in steps:

1. `e.Row.FindControl("Label1")`: find the control with name `Label1` inside the data grid row, returning the found control as an `Control` or null if not found;
2. `((Label)...)`: since `FindControl` returns an `Control`, and we know it is a `Label` (and we want to use some properties from `Label`), we have to tell the compiler to cast it;
3. `(...).Text`: get the text property from the label.